# ArcMap 10.8 and AGOL - Create local copy of Hosted Feature Layer only brings in polygons

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, editing, feature-layer

I have a hosted Feature Layer with points, lines, and polygons in AGOL that users need to be able to edit in ArcMap 10.8.  Editing is enabled at the Feature Layer level and there are no identifiable differences in AGOL between the points, lines, and polygons as far as editing privileges are concerned.

When initiating the Edit Features->Create Local Copy for Editing, only the polygons are copied to the local geodatabase.  The source for the points and lines remains the AGOL service.  Another user has tested and verified that they experience an identical issue with a different dataset so it doesn't really appear to be related to my specific configuration of the dataset on AGOL.

I have extensively reviewed ESRI documentation and can't find any reference to others with this problem.  I've also tried multiple iterations of editing permissions on the Feature Layer unsuccessfully.

Comment: ArcGIS doesn't support the concept of a layer with point, line, *and* polygon geometries. It's not possible to do so.

Comment: It's a Feature Layer so it can contain multiple geometries.
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/feature-layers.htm

Comment: Just throwing out this idea. I have experienced the multi-layer "layer" in agol and how it treats it all as a single layer with regards to collector. I avoided this by publishing each layer separately rather than publishing the map which has that affect of grouping all the layers in your map into that single featurelayer. Try that publish them up onto agol as separate featurelayers.